# AJAX does not get triggered, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

Now it only get the AuctionId value in to the controller the other props are either null or 0...

Here is the form:

```
<form id="createBid">
        <div id="frmBid" class="form-inline">
            <input name="Bidder" asp-for="@bidModel.Bidder" value="@User.Identity.Name" type="hidden" />
            <input name="AuctionId" asp-for="@bidModel.AuctionId" value="@Model.AuctionId" type="hidden" id="auctionId" />
            <label asp-for="@bidModel.Amount" />
            <input name="Amount" asp-for="@bidModel.Amount" />
            <button type="submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Lägg</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here is the action in the controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddBid(BidModel Bid)
{
    var result = await _bidBusinessInterface.CreateBidAsync(Bid, Bid.AuctionId);
    if (result)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Bud lagt!";

    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Bud förlågt!";
    }
    return RedirectToAction("ViewDetails");
}
```

And then we have the actual AJAX call:

```
    $('#createBid').on('submit', function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddBid")',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: function (html)
            {
                $('#frmBid').html(html);
            }
        });
});
```

I'm posting the model here aswell, if it is needed to see where it goes wrong:

```
public class BidModel
{
    [JsonProperty("BudID")]
    public string BidId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Summa")]
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("AuktionID")]
    public string AuctionId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Budgivare")]
    public string Bidder { get; set; }
}
```

I'm very **grateful** for every answer! This has been bugging me for 2 hours..

Comment: Is the generated url is correct? Did you tried to call your controller with Postman? Did you checked if the data/data format are correct? I don't think `serialize` is what you should use.

Comment: Generated URL? Yeah i know the controller works, i’ve used it before with a non AJAX request

Comment: In your browser, do you see the request? Is the http code 200 after the request ends?

Comment: Do you see the POST occurring in the network tab of your browser? What response do you get?

Comment: No I don't see it :P

Comment: I get an error with AJAX, and I think I know what the problem is, it is that I'm not using the layout in my partialView and my layout has the cdn for AJAX, should I add them into the Partial aswell?

Comment: One of the reasons why your action method is not invoked is binder not being able to create BidModel param. Seeing your model annotated with [JsonProperty], you should specify in your AJAX call **contentType: 'application/json'** and **data: JSON.stringify($form.serialize())**

Comment: I don't understand, how will I solve that?

Comment: I get this error: POST https://localhost:44330/Home/AddBid 500 ()
send @ jquery.js:9600
ajax @ jquery.js:9206
(anonymous) @ VM28:9
dispatch @ jquery.js:5183
elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4991

Comment: Now it work and I can debug the action, now it stands that every value is null

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Some value are null AJAX call to controller ASP.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343366/some-value-are-null-ajax-call-to-controller-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 0):

You are using your asp helpers wrong.

let's take this sample of code:

`<input name="Bidder" asp-for="@bidModel.Bidder" value="@User.Identity.Name" type="hidden" />`

you set the `name` to "Bidder" this is what the data will be bound to, when you need "Bid.Bidder" since "Bid" is the name of the object that the action receives.

Now you DO NOT need to set the `name` attribute since `asp-for` helper does it for you, it will automatically generate name, id attributes for you.

now make sure at the top of you page you have `@model YourNamespace.BidModel`

and reference it like so:

`<input asp-for="@Model.Bidder" value="@User.Identity.Name" type="hidden" />`

the attributes will be generated automatically and the model should be bound correctly.

Comment: Problem is that they are going to create a new bid on an Auction and the Auction is the Model that is bound to the view, that's my struggle

Comment: @Charlie do you have `[HttpPost]` attribute above your action?

Comment: Yeah I have, the wierd thing is.
I now get AuctionID value into the controller but the rest is null:
I update my question with how the form looks now